# How can I rotate the elements in my navbar using CSS?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to have my navbar rotate in my WordPress website but can't achieve to have it centered and closed to the left side of the screen.

This is a screenshot of what I got right now:

[image]

This is the code CSS I'm using:

```
nav.standard {
    position: fixed;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(90deg);
    transform: rotate(90deg);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's a clean way to do it and have it stick to the side of the page.

Line-by-line breakdown of relevant bit (full live demo below):

```css
/* fix the bar */
position: fixed;
/* since we're rotating, set its width to the screen height */
width: 100vh;
bottom: 0;
/* push our bar into the screen by its height (2em) */
right: 2em;
line-height: 2em;
/* rotate 90deg clockwise */
transform: rotate(90deg);
/* use the bottom-right as rotation point */
transform-origin: 100% 100%;
```

```css
.nav {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  text-align: center;
  white-space: nowrap;

  position: fixed;
  width: 100vh;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 2em;
  line-height: 2em;
  transform: rotate(90deg);
  transform-origin: 100% 100%;
}

.nav li {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 1em;
}
```

```html
<ul class="nav">
  <li>Page 1</li>
  <li>Page 2</li>
  <li>Page 3</li>
  <li>Page 4</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Hi Jon! I have tried your code and nothing seems to be working... Take a look: https://www.tontcho.es/project/prueba?preview_id=5396&preview=true

Comment: @Tontcho I can't tell on which elements you have tried applying my CSS.

Comment: Hi @Jon, I have apply the css code you gave to me: `nav {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  text-align: center;
  white-space: nowrap;

  position: fixed;
  width: 100vh;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 2em;
  line-height: 2em;
  transform: rotate(90deg);
  transform-origin: 100% 100%;
}

.nav li {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 1em;
}`

Answer (score 1):

You could use `writing-mode: vertical-lr;` in combination with `transform: rotate(180deg);`.

```css
body {
background-color: #eee;
}

nav.standard {
position: absolute;
left: 0;
top: 0;
bottom: 0;
text-align: center;
-webkit-writing-mode: vertical-lr;
-moz-writing-mode: vertical-lr;
-ms-writing-mode: vertical-lr;
writing-mode: vertical-lr;
transform: rotate(180deg);
background-color: #FFF;
}

nav.standard a {
  color: #333;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0.8em 0.4em;
  font-size: .75rem;
}
```

```html
<nav class="standard">
 <a href="#">— Home</a>
 <a href="#">— About</a>
 <a href="#">— Portfolio</a>
 <a href="#">— Contact</a>
</nav>
```

Comment: Hi Daniel! Thanks for helping. Your code seems to have weird results, take a look: https://www.dropbox.com/s/vgah67qvd9hjki0/Captura%20de%20pantalla%202017-11-28%20a%20las%2020.12.01.png?dl=0

Comment: Please have a look at the code snippet provided and how it behaves in the editor there.
Without seeing your code it is hard to tell, what other CSS is interfering with the snippet on your live site. An image doesn't help, I'm afraid.

Comment: Hey Daniel, in your snippet it works but in my live site it isn´t... Thanks a lot for trying anyway. Iam amateur about css and stuff and can´t find what it´s interfering... I you wanna check: https://www.tontcho.es/project/prueba?preview_id=5396&preview=true

Comment: I can't find my CSS on your page. Your menu has the following CSS:
`.semplice-navbar [data-nav=logo-left-menu-right] nav ul, 
.semplice-navbar [data-nav=logo-left-menu-left] nav ul, 
.semplice-navbar [data-nav=logo-right-menu-left] nav ul, 
.semplice-navbar [data-nav=logo-right-menu-right] nav ul, 
.semplice-navbar [data-nav=logo-middle-menu-stacked] nav ul {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: flex-end;
    padding: 0;
    height: 100%;
    align-items: center;
}`, coming from frontend-min.css